# XCode UICollectionViewCell appearing much smaller on simulator than in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am creating an application that uses UICollectionView. I have a UIImageView inside the UICollectionViewCell. On the storyboard, the size of the UICollectionViewCell and the image is correct but when I try running it on the simulator, the image that appears on the simulator is much smaller relative to the view controller. I tried changing the size of the cell but the image always appeared on the simulator as the same much smaller size. I thought it might be because the image might be too small even though I set it to be the same dimensions as the cell so I used an image with dimensions about 50 pixels larger than the current image. But it still defaults to the much smaller size as before when I run it on the simulator. I would really appreciate help regarding this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. try placing your setupUI in

   `viewDidAppear` instead on `viewDidLoad`
2. and what type of iPhone you run and what type of iPhone when you use storyboard?
   well, if you use iPhone 5s in your storyboard it'll sure look bigger than 10+ right?

because iphone 5 has smaller resolution than 10

3. You need to post your code, because i can't really assume what is your issue